# Bash script to find file name that containts specific range of numbers

Tags: xml, linux, bash, shell, grep

I have a bunch of .NFO files that contain metadata (which is basically in XML format) about movies. I want to create a bash script that loops through all the .NFO files and lists the file names that contain ratings equal to or less than 5.0. The rating is placed in a XML tag `<rating>number</rating>`.

I was able to use `grep` to find a specific word in the text file and it worked for a :

```
grep "rating" . -R
```

The result is `movie_name.nfo: <rating>7.5</rating>`

I tried the following but it did not work:

```
grep "<rating>[0.0-9.0]</rating>" . -R
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Ranges doesn't work like that with regular expressions. Think of it more as continuous characters in a character set.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU grep:

```
grep -oP '<rating>\K(5\.0|[0-4]\.[0-9])(?=<)'
```

Output (e.g.)

```
4.3
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this gnu `grep` solution:

```
echo "movie_name.nfo: <rating>4.5</rating>" | grep -Eo "[0-4]\.[[:digit:]]+|5\.0"
4.5
```

Here we are using extended regex to match any value less than or equal to `5.0` by matching `5.0` or any digit between 0 and 4, then a literal dot and then one or more occurrences of digits (0-9).

As per your comment you can try the following `sed` solution which will ensure that no unwanted value is getting selected:

```
sed -nr 's/.*<rating>([0-4]\.[[:digit:]]+|5\.0).*/\1/p' file.txt
```

Comment: @heemyl: This looks promising but if I used against a movie metadata file then it will retrieve every other digit in the file. I tried the following and it worked in retrieving <rating>7.5</rating>:

grep -Eo "<rating>[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+</rating>"
but how can I find the digits less then or equal a number in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a `xml` parser, like `XML::Twig` of the `perl` language. It is a simple program and depends in the shell that you are using, can invoke it with regular expression syntax to pass many files in the same command. The code is as simple as:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

for my $f (@ARGV) {
    XML::Twig->new(
        twig_handlers => {
            'rating' => sub {
                printf qq|%s\n|, $f if $_->text_only && $_->text_only < 5;
            },  
        },  
    )->parsefile($f);
}
```

And called like:

```
perl script.pl xmlfile*
```

It will output the name of every file that contains any `<rating>` element with a value below 5.